# Logic Problem I can't fix. (Sorry for the title)

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, sorry for the inconsistent title. I don't know how to describe my problem correctly.

I've been learning Python for about 2 weeks now so please forgive me for being such a noob.

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name=0, password=0):
        self.name = name 
        self.password = password
        
    
def createAcc():
    username = input("Name: ")
    userpass = input("Password: ")
    
    userList.append(User(username, userpass))
    
    
def loginAcc():
    accName = input("Account Name: ")
    if accName in userList:
        print("Hi")
    
    
userList = []
createAcc()
loginAcc()
```

The problem here is that it's not printing "Hi" which is probably because of the line

```
if accName in userList:
```

I know that it is because of the way i inserted my "user" into the list.
For example i put name as "Jeff"
The string "Jeff" really isn't in userList so when i try to call it, it doesn't work

Great i understand the problem but how do i fix it? I don't know..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps if your usernames are unique, you could change `userList` to a dict. Then you could look up the user object by name.

Comment: The only thing that makes sense here is to use a dictionary indexed by the user name.  One of the answers below shows how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have suggested looping your list to get the name, but I thought I'd give a different approach. By using a dictionary instead of a list you can look up the User objects by their name or just search it by it's keys(). So your code would look like this:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name=0, password=0):
        self.name = name 
        self.password = password
        
    
def createAcc():
    username = input("Name: ")
    userpass = input("Password: ")
    userDict[username] = User(username, userpass)
    
    
def loginAcc():
    accName = input("Account Name: ")
    if accName in userDict.keys(): # check if accName is a key in the dict
        print("Hi")
    
    print(userDict[accName].password) # or just access objects directly using their key.
    
userDict = dict()
createAcc()
loginAcc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `loginAcc` function with this:

```py
def loginAcc():
    accName = input("Account Name: ")
    for account in userList:
        if account.name == accName:
            print("Hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension to extract the user names from userList:

```
def loginAcc():
    accName = input("Account Name: ")
    if accName in [u.name for u in userList]:
        print("Hi")
```